# Getting required data before app initialize in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, observable

I've created a service which gets some data from server and they are required for making my components and should be called once because it causes a huge load on server. when I use service in app module provider it waits until getting the required data and it does get it successfully because I can log it but after that when I want to get it in component it returns Undefined!

I've tried to reduce initializations of service to 1 by removing UserService from providers but it causes errors.

Function that gets info:

```
getAdminInitInfo(): Promise<any> {
var vm = this;
const promise = this.http.get<AdminInit>(baseUrl + '/panel/admin/initial/')
  .toPromise()
  .then(
    response => {
      vm.adminInitInfo = response;
      console.log(response);
    }
  )
return promise;
}
```

Factory that would be used in APP_INITIALIZATION:

```
export function adminProviderFactory(provider: UserService) {
  return () => provider.getAdminInitInfo();
}
```

AppModule providers:

```
providers: [
    AuthGuardService,
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorService,
      multi: true
    },
    UserService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: adminProviderFactory,
      deps: [UserService],
      multi: true
    }
]
```

Log of data I get in component:

```
user.service.ts:23 service started 
user.service.ts:23 service started 
user.service.ts:70 {filters: {…}}
user.service.ts:78 undefined
overview.component.ts:19 undefined
```

After this procedure the adminInitInfo should be return anytime I need it using this function:

```
getSomethingData() {
    var data = {};
    console.log(this.adminInitInfo);
    if (!this.adminInitInfo) {
      return undefined;
    }
    data['something'] = this.adminInitInfo.filters.something;
    data['something2'] = this.adminInitInfo.filters.something2;
    data['something3'] = this.adminInitInfo.filters.something3;
    return data;
}
```

In a component such as:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.params = this.userService.getSomethingData();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking is a way to have component requirements fulfilled. This can be done by using a resolver in your routing.

The key ingredients are the following:

**The service** which has the information your require (`ApplicationData` is a class of mine that contains information about the application such user name, version, etc..., it is irrelevant in this context):

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {
    private cachedData: ApplicationData = null;

    public constructor(/* place here your dependencies */) {
    }

    public initializeApplicationData(): Observable<ApplicationData> {
        // return here the observable that builds your application data, like for example getting the user, and joining it with the version and tap it:

        // if we already have the data, don't ask anything and simply return it
        if (this.cachedData)
            return of(this.cachedData);

        return /* your service that builds the application data */.getApplicationData().pipe(
            tap(x=> this.cachedData = x));
    }

    public getCachedData(): ApplicationData {
       return this.cachedData;
    }
}
```

**The resolver** that is the piece of code that is run before your route takes place and resolves everything you need. The resolver is completed, when observer is completed.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedAppResolver implements Resolve<Observable<ApplicationData>> {

    public constructor(private applicationService: ApplicationService) { }

    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<ApplicationData> {
        return this.applicationService.initializeApplicationData();
    }
}
```

**The routing** that is, simply protect your routing with the resolver:

```
    path: '',
    component: MyLayout,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
        { path: 'page', component: APage2Component },
    ],
    resolve: { data: AuthenticatedAppResolver },
```

Your components and service must be registers in the `providers` section of your module. Then you can freely use the `getCachedData()` method of the `ApplicationService` in any components protected by the resolver.

Note that the resolver may be invoked more than once, but, as we cache in the service, we won't ask them every time.

**Update**

This method works until you have 1 level of sub modules. If it gets more complicated or you wanted more than 1 module to use these datas it's better to create a parent module and resolve the whole route then, write routings in the routing module of that.
Example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyLayout,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: DashboardComponent
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'publisher',
        loadChildren: './modules/publisher/publisher.module#PublisherModule'
      }
    ],
    resolve: {
      data: AuthenticatedAppResolver
    }
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your approach is too complicated. And you never return the value of `response`. Try it this way instead:

```
getAdminInitInfo(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get<AdminInit>(baseUrl + '/panel/admin/initial/')
    .toPromise()
    .then(
         response => { return response.json(); }
    );
}
```

`response.json()` already returns a promise.

Or even shorter:

```
getAdminInitInfo(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get<AdminInit>(baseUrl + '/panel/admin/initial/')
    .toPromise()
    .then(
         response => response.json()
    );
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to return it in getAdminInitInfo. It should be returned in another function without calling the API anymore. Actually all I want to achieve is calling API once and use its data in various components several times. I edited the question to make it more clear.